# How do I check if the following items are in the a list?

Tags: python

I need to check if list f is inside bolsa. Then, i should add f in carteira_acoes.

```
bolsa = {"ibm": 100.0, "google": 200.0, "microsoft": 100.0, "x": 40.0}
carteira_acoes = [["ibm",10],["google",20]]
f = ["x", 40]
if (f[0]) in bolsa.items():
    carteira_acoes.append(f)
print (carteira_acoes)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You said you need to check if list F is in bolsa, but you only checked f[0], which is the first item of F. So, do you need to check if first item of F is in bolsa, or the whole list F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you give here, I think the problem may be simple:  you're looking in bolsa.items(), when all you need is to find the *key*.  Try changing this one line:

```
if f[0] in bolsa:
```

Referring to the dictionary name returns a list of the keys.

You will also want to iterate through the "wants" list `f`.  Note that all you really need in the list is the key, `x`, rather than trying to look for the `40` as well (if that was in your plans).  You can simply extract the 40 from the original dictionary.

Comment: Tksss! I did it a tried a few minutes ago and i succeeded !! Tks anyway !

Comment: Sure.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.  You can also delete the question, if you feel it doesn't have any value to future programmers.